# How do you hide/show a dynamic element in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic, graphics

Here is the simplified version of the problem:

`THIS: {1,2,##&[],4,5} RETURNS: {1,2,4,5}`

`AND THIS: x=##&[]; {1,2,Dynamic[x],4,5} RETURNS: {1,2,StandardForm,4,5}`

I want to hide`"StandardForm"`when the dynamic variable`"x"`is equal to`"##&[]"`.

Here is the full version of the code I am working with:

```
Column[{
    Panel["Panel 1"],
    Panel["Panel 2"],
    Annotation[Panel["Panel 3"], Panel["Extra Panel"], "Mouse"],
    Dynamic[MouseAnnotation[## &[]]],
    Panel["Panel 4"]
}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Here I want to create a column of 4 equally spaced panels where if I mouse over panel 3, an extra panel appears in between panels 3 and 4.

If I use`"##&[]"`it returns`"Null"`in between panels 3 and 4. If I use`""`instead,  it returns a blank space in between panels 3 and 4, but the space is larger than the rest found in the column.

Is there a solution or work around to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Column[{Panel["Panel 1"], Panel["Panel 2"], 
  Mouseover[Panel["Panel 3"], Column@{Panel["Panel 3"], Panel["Extra Panel"]}], 
  Panel["Panel 4"]}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Column[{Panel["Panel 1"], Panel["Panel 2"], 
  Dynamic@If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
       Column@{Panel["Panel 3"], Panel["Extra Panel"]}, Panel["Panel 3"]], 
  Panel["Panel 4"]}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

It is functional, but the unequal spacing still remains. This method also introduces a pixel shift which I am not too happy about.

Modifying your code a bit I was able to remove the extra space in the column, but the pixel shift during rollover still remains.

`Column[Join[{Panel["Panel 1"],Panel["Panel 2"]},{Mouseover[Panel["Panel 3"],Column[{Panel["Panel 3"],Panel["Extra Panel"]},Spacings->{0, 0}]]},{Panel["Panel 4"]}],Spacings->{0, 0}]`

Comment: @user12572, my pleasure. I don't know what "pixel shift" is; can you pls explain?

Comment: ... does it help if you use `Pane[#, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}] &` to wrap the `Column[...]`? or just add `BaselinePosition -> Top` to `Column`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you <3